# Foundation Zurb

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have a quick HTML foundation question. I am using foundation for my HTML page. I want to know how to do a photo gallery that has next and pervious and auto play with a description under each photo any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check **Slick slider** which is also recommended by Zurb:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

*(Orbit Slider by Zurb is already deprecated)*

Answer (score 0):

Foundation has a build in element called *Orbit* for that: [Orbit Carousel](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html)

You can access the plugin options directly via *data attributes.*